# NMinimize is wrong : why?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Consider the following code:

```
A = 575;
B = 291;
pMeBis[k_, delta_, nAvg_] := 
 1/Binomial[A, 
    2]*(Binomial[A, 
      2]*(delta/Binomial[A, 2] + Pi^2/16*(B^k)/nAvg))^(2^k)
NMinimize[pMeBis[k, 0.9, 10^31], k \[Element] Integers]
```

It tells me: {0., {k -> 8}}

So the minimal value is for k=8.

However, I have:

```
In[24]:= pMeBis[8, 0.9, 10^31]

Out[24]= 1.17111*10^-17

In[25]:= pMeBis[10, 0.9, 10^31]

Out[25]= 2.02939*10^-31
```

Thus, Mathematica is wrong. Why is it so ?

Answer (score 6):

The numerical portion of the `NMinimize` function likely gets confused with all the large powers of 10. Try the non-numeric version instead, making sure to use only integers or rational numbers, so it does not convert to numerics automatically:

```
Minimize[pMeBis[k, 9/10, 10^31], k ∈ Integers]//N
```

> {0., {k -> 10.}}

Answer (score 5):

`NMinimize` finds the solution if you increase the `WorkingPrecision`

```
NMinimize[pMeBis[k, 0.9, 10^31], k \[Element]Integers,WorkingPrecision -> 50]
(*{2.0293883409099669577878953337601566621641181036332*10^-31, {k ->10}}*)
```